# Porting a C++ project into an iOS app?

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

> project compiles fine, how do I export it as an iOS app though

I have a large C++ project that I'd like to turn into an iOS app... any tips on how I might go about doing this? What I've done so far is to use CMake to generate an XCode project. I've been able to subsequently build (and archive -- but I can't find the archives in the organizer) my project in XCode, but to my understanding this is merely using XCode as an IDE...

Is there an easy way to remedy this situation? Or do I need to reconstruct the project all over again iOS style. If so, any guides you might recommend?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What type of C++ project is this? You can use C++ freely (almost) with Objective-C.

Comment: You seem to have created a macOS target, not an iOS one.

Comment: Hi guys, its a project that uses the OpenCV library and runs facial detection... I agree with the macOS comment, but I didn't ever choose? just cmake -G XCode, any tips?

Comment: You can compile C++ files in Xcode.

Comment: Indeed, I can compile the project, but how would I get it exported as a working iPhone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.mm files compile to objective-c++.

This is how you will get c++ code to talk to all the IOS libraries, which unfortunately are only generally easily available in objective-c and swift.

So create c++ interfaces in .h or .hpp files, and back them up with an objective-c++ impl that then talks to the objective-c runtime.

To get cmake to work nicely with iOS, you'll need a toolchain file.

There is a nice collection that you can use as a starting point here:

https://github.com/ruslo/polly

Comment: I'm trying to reDL OpenCV as an iOS framework... previously I was linking it as external C++ libs... maybe will help, TQ